# Is my understanding of Italian rugby "Serie A" correct?

Tags: rugby-union, promotions, relegations

I've created [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hHbY7xFG8GnBW2NmDVoGiLu7NMbHqtN0uWgYdGSVpEc/edit?usp=sharing) to summarise the Italian rugby "Serie A" (II and III division) format, based on [this table](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campionato_italiano_di_rugby_a_15#Struttura_dei_tornei): problem is, while the linked table is quite clear and reasonable, it's full of contradicting descriptions otherwhere ([such as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Championship_of_Excellence#Format) [these](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_A_di_rugby_a_15#Formato) [three](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_A2_di_rugby_a_15_2013-2014#Classifica)), that's why I'm asking.

Posting a screenshot, just in case:
[image]

The contradictions include:

1. a match between A.A:10th and A.B:2nd, the winner goes to A.A and the loser to A.B
2. three teams directly relegated from A.B to B instead of two

The first contradiction just makes no sense, since it would cause to have 13 teams in A.A vs. 11 teams in A.B, but it strikes me as odd if someone completely made it up from thin air...

The second contradiction might be caused by the bankruptcy of Amatori Catania, but I fail to see how this would cause one more team to be relegated: I would have guessed they would just eat up the 12th place instead.